# How to write expression for special KV string in logstash kv fiter?

Tags: logstash-configuration, elastic-stack

I got plenty of logs like these kind of stuff:

```
uid[118930] pageview h5_act, actTag[cyts] corpId[2] inviteType[0] clientId[3] clientVer[2.3.0] uniqueId[d317de16a78a0089b0d94d684e7a9585565ffa236138c0.85354991] srcId[0] subSrc[]
```

Most of these are key-value expression in KEY[VALUE] form.

I have read the [document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-kv.html) but still cannot figure out how to write the configurations.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply configure your `kv` filter using the `value_split` and `trim` settings, like below:

```
filter {
  kv {
    value_split => "\["
    trim => "\]"
  }
}
```

For the sample log line you've given, you'll get:

```
{
       "message" => "uid[118930] pageview h5_act, actTag[cyts] corpId[2] inviteType[0] clientId[3] clientVer[2.3.0] uniqueId[d317de16a78a0089b0d94d684e7a9585565ffa236138c0.85354991] srcId[0] subSrc[]",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2015-12-12T05:04:00.888Z",
          "host" => "iMac.local",
           "uid" => "118930",
        "actTag" => "cyts",
        "corpId" => "2",
    "inviteType" => "0",
      "clientId" => "3",
     "clientVer" => "2.3.0",
      "uniqueId" => "d317de16a78a0089b0d94d684e7a9585565ffa236138c0.85354991",
         "srcId" => "0",
        "subSrc" => ""
}
```

Comment: Nope, there could be a string like [[...]], and this method dose not work out that case.

Comment: Was it the case or just gut feeling?

Comment: I just address this issue by using this way:  
     mutate {       gsub => [
          "kvs", "\[", "=",
          "kvs", "\]", "&"
        ]
      }
      kv {
        source => "kvs"
        field_split => "& "
      }

Comment: Not perfect way. cannot trim ] since that the real sperator.